# How to mark elements that can have click events?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

Up until now, I've been using `id` to trigger click events in jquery, like:

```
<button class="btn" id="doAction">Action</button>

$(document).on('click', '#doAction', function ()
{
    // handle the click event
}
```

However, what if I have multiple elements on the page that should trigger the same click event?

For example:

```
<button class="btn" id="doAction">Action</button>
...
<span class="action-trigger" id="doAction">Action</div>

$(document).on('click', '#doAction', function ()
{
    // handle the click event
}
```

The problem with this is that there should only exist one unique `id` on any given page.

**My question is, what are modern conventions to deal with this?**

One solution I thought of was to add a `data-action="doAction"` property to each element that should trigger the click event.

Is this a good way to solve this or are there better ways?

Comment: yes, data-action="doAction" is a very acceptable way to do it.

Comment: most people use a `class` - because an element can have multiple classes ... `class="btn doAction"` and `class="something doAction"` will both be selected using `'.doAction'` for example

Comment: @JaromandaX It seems weird using `class` when there are no CSS properties defined for it.

Comment: @user6945880 not at all, this would be a normal use for a `class`

Comment: As an aside, having click events on spans isn't very user-friendly, because users who are restricted (for whatever reason) to using a keyboard can't click those items. If you use anchors then keyboard users can still tab to them and "click" them (and of course you can still style them).

Comment: @user6945880 - sure, but it's not incorrect to do so

Comment: As an addendum to @nnnnnn's aside, click events on spans may not work properly on mobile devices. For example, with iphone, the clickable span MUST have the css rule `cursor: pointer` for the click to register

Comment: I deleted the comment because I realised that too

Answer (score 4):

You can use a class as well. I personally prefer to use a prefix `js-` and do not add CSS styles to those, e.g.: `js-doaction`:

```
$(document).on('click', '.js-doaction', function() {
    // handle the click event
}
```

html:

```
<button class="btn js-doaction">Action</button>
...
<span class="action-trigger js-doaction">Action</div>
```

Comment: It seems a bit odd using a `class` when not CSS properties have been defined for it.

Comment: Are there any advantages of using `class` over a `data-action` property?

Comment: @user6945880 - Using `class` is a common practice. If the element already has classes then you save several characters by not having to create a `data-` attribute as well as `class`. But if you prefer `data-whatever` then just do that, it's a valid alternative.

Comment: @user6945880 no more than using `#someId` would be odd. Ids are just as much CSS selectors as classes. jQuery is built with using CSS selectors in mind. Using any selector you wish would be appropriate and I'd say `class` is by far the most widely used for such use cases.